# What makes a comedy series a sitcom?

Tags: comedy, genre, sitcoms, the-good-place

What exactly is a sitcom? In particular: what distinguishes sitcoms among the (presumably) broader category of comedy series?

It's easy enough to give classical examples of sitcoms. They tend to have several common features: usually there is a recurring set of characters who are put in comical situations, often there is a laugh track, usually it's pure comedy (as opposed to comedy + action, or comedy + fantasy, etc.), usually plot progression is relatively slow.

I'm curious which features are essential for a series to be considered a sitcom. This question arose from an attempt to figure out if *The Good Place* is a sitcom; it seems to be something of an edge case. However, I'm more interested in a general answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Situational Comedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitcom)

> A sitcom, short for "situation comedy", is a genre of comedy centered
>   **on a fixed set of characters who carry over from episode to episode**.
>   Sitcoms can be contrasted with sketch comedy, where a troupe may use
>   new characters in each sketch, and stand-up comedy, where a comedian
>   tells jokes and stories to an audience. **Sitcoms originated in radio,
>   but today are found mostly on television as one of its dominant
>   narrative forms. This form can also include mockumentaries**.
>
> A situation comedy television program may be recorded in front of a
>   studio audience, depending on the program's production format. The
>   effect of a live studio audience can be imitated or enhanced by the
>   use of a laugh track. During filming productions, the laugh track is
>   usually prerecorded.

---

I think we are seeing a lot more diverse definitions of comedy and comedy-drama over the years.

For instance, the TV series [Chuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_(TV_series)) is sort of uniquely brilliant, because it takes two situational comedies with his family life being like *Friends* and his Buymore life being like *Superstore* (workplace comedy) and marries them with a spy action dramedy.

In terms of the Good Place, I could see how it is categorized as such, because of how it fixates on a particular place with mostly the same characters, even though I would agree it seems to touch drama and could almost be considered a fantasy situational dramedy